# setters and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco-libraries

I have an issue with threads in C++.

I have 2 threads running: one running a client and one functioning as a listener. The listener thread calls a `shutdown()` method, which only does the following:

```
shutdown_=true;
std::cout<<shutdown_<<std::endl;
```

`shutdown_` is set as volatile, and the listener thread is the only one that calls the `shutdown()` method, and it is only accessed while the other thread is in `wait()` mode (`Poco synchronizedObject wait()`).

For some reason the `cout` keeps printing "0", and initially (while using xcode) I got a warning saying that the line `shutdown_=true` doesn't do anything. This warning disappeared after a few compiles.

I tried using a Mutex lock, locking and unlocking before and after the line, to no effect.
I ended up removing the function `shutDown()` completely and instead of using it, I changed `shutDown_` to be public, and accessed it directly from the listener thread as follows:

```
client_->shutdown_=true
```

That works fine. I just have no idea what the problem was, and how to avoid it in the future.

Thanks,

Comment: On the face of it, the compiler warning doesn't make much sense... are you sure you didn't accidentally have shutdown_==true; ?  It might also be helpful to post more of your code.

Comment: on another note, how exactly do i mark questions as solved ?

Comment: click the checkmark to the left of the correct answer.

Comment: James, you might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's linked to at the top right from every page on SO.

Comment: "Poco"? XCode? That sounds like Objective-C, does it not? If so, that might explain a bit -- I pure C++ from your explanation I can not see what happens. What is the type of `shutdown_`? What is `true` (i.e. in C++ its a keyword/constant, but is it in your code as well?). I an mot sure about the `volatile` though... I you only set `shutdown_` at that location.

Comment: What type is `shutdown_` ? You're sure the `0` you're getting is printed by the `shutdown()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you defined the shutdown_ member volatile. Did you perhaps hide the inherited base variable?